# JObject.ToObject with errors to Model State

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, bad-request

In an ASP.NET core project, I've switched from using `ResourceModel` to using `JObject` as my `[FromBody]` parameter. I then pass `JObject.ToObject<ResourceModel>()` into a service, but want to maintain the `JObject` itself for the `ContainsKey` and similar functionality.

If `JObject.ToObject<T>` succeeds, I can use `TryValidateModel()` and, if that fails, return `BadRequest(ModelState)` simply enough. However, the problem I'm running into is when `JObject.ToObject<T>` throws an exception - I'm unsure how to capture the serialization errors in the `ModelState`.

Example:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public uint Age {get;set;}
}
public class CommonParameters {
    [FromQuery] public string? Fields {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public IPAddress? RequestorIp {get;set;}
    public JObject? JsonBody {get;set;}
}
public class PersonController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly PersonService _personService;
    // this is how I had been doing it
    [HttpPatch("obsolete/{id}")] // this method doesn't actually exist, but is shown for the example
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePerson([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Person parameters, [FromHeader] CommonParameters commonParameters) {
         SetCommonParameters(commonParameters, parameters);
         // if parameters.Age in the json body was a string, BadRequest is returned before this method even starts
         _personService.Set(parameters);
         await _personService.SaveChangesAsync();
         return NoContent();
    }
    // this is how I'm trying to do it now, so that I only update Age if JObject.ContainsKey("Age")
    // instead of parameters.Age != default, etc.
    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePerson([FromRoute] int Id, [FromBody] JObject parameters, [FromHeader] CommonParameters commonParameters) {
         SetCommonParameters(commonParameters, parameters);
         // if parameters.Age is a string in this version, a JsonReaderException 
         // or JsonSerializationException is thrown when I call JObject.ToObject<>()
         // and I have to validate the model separately after that
         // what this means is, a BadRequest with the ModelState errors is not
         // returned if there's an issue with the json.
         var model = parameters.ToObject<Person>();
         if (!TryValidateModel(model)) return BadRequest(ModelState);
         _personService.Set(person);
         await _personService.SaveChangesAsync();
         return NoContent();
    }
    private void SetCommonParameters(CommonParameters commonParameters, JObject? jsonBody = null) {
        commonParameters.JsonBody = jsonBody;
        commonParameters.UserName = User.Identity?.Name;
        commonParameters.RequestorIp = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: As Guru Stron has asked, here's an example of an invalid model/json object.

Model:

```
public class ContactInfo {
  // PhoneNumber being a struct representing an 11-digit phone number
  // PhoneType being an enum of Cell, Work, Home, etc.
  public Dictionary<PhoneType, PhoneNumber[]> PhoneNumbers {get;set;} = new();
  public string? Apartment {get;set;}
  public int AddressNumber {get;set;}
  public string StreetName {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}
  // State being an enum of the 50 United States of America
  public State State {get;set;}
}
```

The invalid json

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": {
    "work": [ "1-111-111-1111" ],
    "home": [ "2-222-222-2222" ],
    "cell": [ "1-800-CALL-NOW" ]
  },
  "apartment": null,
  "addressNumber": "3a",
  "streetName": "Imagination St.",
  "city": "Atlantis",
  "state": "Atlantic"
}
```

In this case, passing the above json for `ContactInfo` to a controller's method that asks for a `ContactInfo` parameter will return a bad request indicating that the state was invalid, the address number was invalid, *and* a phone number was invalid - without testing this specifically, something like the following.

```
{
  "errors": {
    "phoneNumbers": [
      "Could not parse phone number \"1-800-CALL-NOW\". The value must be an 11-digit numeric value."
    ],
    "addressNumber": [
      "The value could not be parsed as int."
    ],
    "state": [
      "\"Atlantic\" is an invalid value for State. The following values are valid: ..."
    ]
  }
}
```

If instead the controller asks for `JObject` and I then call `JObject.ToObject` and catch an exception, I'll get *one* of those errors - such as `Could not parse phone number "1-800-CALL-NOW". The value must be an 11-digit numeric value.` The others will be ignored until that one is fixed and the user tries again.

Comment: You can catch the exception and add it's text as model level error with `ModelState.AddModelError("", ...)`

Comment: Unfortunately that will catch only a single exception - the first parsed error - instead of all of them that may occur.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples for invalid json and expected errors output.

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated the post to include an example at the bottom.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the errors of ModelState?If so,you can use `foreach (var item in ModelState)` to foreach the errors of ModelState.

Comment: @YiyiYou I want to identify every error that prevents converting the `JObject` to the `T` passed to `ToObject<T>()` method (not just the first one such as is represented by the exception) and add them all to `ModelState` so that I can return a BadRequest explaining all errors preventing me from converting `JObject` to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

I've at last figured it out... All that I need to do is provide a JsonSerializer to `JObject.ToObject<>` and include an error handler that marks errors as handled. For example:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Error += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.ErrorContext.Error is JsonException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(args.ErrorContext.Path, args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
};

var value = parameters.ToObject<Person>(serializer);
if (!TryValidateModel(value)) return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
```

It is my understanding that the default `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonInputFormater` performs similar error handling; I'm still not sure how to use that handler directly, but what I have here is working for what I need.